# ImageMagick tiling outputs two files

Tags: imagemagick

i'm trying to repeat a single image tiling it with imagemagick. i've come to this:

```
montage v.png -duplicate 12 -tile 4x3 -geometry +0+0 temp.png
```

but i'm getting two output images with different names, temp-0.png and temp-1.png, which is troubling the next steps of the script. temp-0 seems to be what i want, but why is temp-1 being created? it contains just a single source image with a big empty space to the right. thanks!

Comment: there are lots of ways to tile. See https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/canvas/#tile or http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/tileimage/index.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you duplicate 12 times, you'll have 13 images in *toto*. Try `-duplicate 11` instead.

Comment: makes sense. i tought the original one counted as a duplicate when tiling. thanks.